# Salesforce get Record types XML

Tags: record-type, xml

I created new Record Type and now I can deploy it to PROD using Change set (Outbound/Inbound) but is there any option to get Record types XML in order I can push that XML to gitlab?

Comment: are you familiar with using sfdx?

Comment: I am pretty new in salesforce so I am really not sure how to do that.

Comment: a good place to start would be [Trailheads](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/projects/quick-start-salesforce-dx)

Comment: I asked here because I couldn't find answer on my question.

Comment: You should do the SFDX trailheads like glls recommended. Most metadata can be pulled from one org to a file system (and though into VCS) and pushed to another using this CLI. Note that there's a unified CLI coming down the tracks from Salesforce too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like the comments suggest, you should be using sfdx, but if you don't want to use that you can extract a XML file for your Record Types using Workbench (https://workbench.developerforce.com/login.php). Here is an example https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000315117&type=1 and the object is called RecordType (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_recordtype.htm)